# Where do I put code to pass a request to the In-app Billing service in Android In App Billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to follow the [In-App Billing tutorial on the Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html). I'm up to Making In-app Billing Requests. There is code I'm supposed to add to my project:

```
ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
skuList.add("premiumUpgrade");
skuList.add("gas");
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
querySkus.putStringArrayList(“ITEM_ID_LIST”, skuList);
```

All well and good, but where do I put this code? In OnCreate()? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the same guide you are following, you must use that code to query if certain items are  available for purchase. And you must call the method `mService.getSkuDetails()`. Like this:

```
Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```

The guide also reads:

> Warning: Do not call the getSkuDetails method on the main thread. Calling this method triggers a network request which could block your main thread. Instead, create a separate thread and call the getSkuDetails method from inside that thread.

So, answering your question, your code must be put inside an `AsyncTask`, preferably inside `doInBackground()` method, because it implicates networking and cannot be done on the main thread.

To learn more about using an `AsyncTask`, check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). 
Hope to have helpe you.

Comment: OK, so the code I referenced in my question goes in the same place as the call of getSkuDetails? That wasn't totally clear to me.

Comment: Yes, your `querySkus` Bundle is a parameter of `getSkuDetails()`.